# pass inputs from python to matlab and return output back to python

Tags: python, matlab, rest, flask

I have a python flask restful API to accept web requests in JSON format.

```
{
  "imageurl":"http://cf067b.medialib.glogster.com/media/ea/ea717410f781940999f24dadaeb0b547dc9aa1289dc17b98ee4d134cec74e73c/t-shirt-in-modal-stretch-png.png"
  "itemlist": [item1, item2, item3]
}
```

I want to pass the contents of imageurl and itemlist as inputs to a Matlab function. I used subprocess to pass parameters to Matlab function. Here is how far I got:

```
@app.route('/testMatlab',methods = ['POST'])
def testMatlab():
url=request.json['imageurl']
taglist=request.json.get('taglist',[])
solve_it(url,taglist)
return jsonify(out)

def solve_it(arg1,arg2):
# Modify this code to run your matlab code
proc=subprocess.call(["matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -wait -r \"myFunction(\'%s\',\'%s\')\"" % (arg1, arg2)],shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stout=subprocess.PIPE);
# Read result from file
out, err = proc.communicate()
print(out)
```

Right now myFunction.m simply returns taglist itself.

How can I return the output of myFunction as a string in JSON. Suppose the results of myFunction is out, I want to pass this results in JSON back to web request, e.g.

```
return jsonify(out)
```

Comment: What is `myFunction`?

Comment: myFunction is the matlab function, it should return a list of polygon shapes

Comment: Ah, missed that. Thanks. `solve_it` needs to return `out` to `testMatlab`.